# RabbitMQ Alternative for Local

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am providing new software design and going to use RabbitMQ as messaging bus along with Spring Cloud Stream.

One of the issues is that the developers cannot install Erlang or RabbitMQ on the local machine.

Spring Cloud stream do not support ActiveMQ. Is there anyway I can install queue on local machine and use that while use RabbitMQ in the unix environment?

Answer (score 2):

A good option is run rabbitmq in a docker container on the local machine. You could use a rabbitmq image [already published on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) and if you want to you could even start it automatically in your integration tests using the [fabric8 maven plugin](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin). We've been [doing that on the Activiti project](https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-runtime-bundle-service/blob/7.0.0.Beta1/activiti-cloud-starter-runtime-bundle/pom.xml#L222), also with spring cloud streams. You could run this in a maven profile so that you only activate it on machines which have docker available.

For tests [apache qpid](https://dzone.com/articles/mocking-rabbitmq-for-integration-tests) might be an option. There aren't many examples with spring cloud streams available right now but there is https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-rabbitmq/pull/12

Comment: Do that require docker to be installed on the windows?

Comment: Yes. Or if it's just for running tests another way might be apache qpid - I'll update my answer to reflect that. Another approach might be to have a profile that runs tests using docker but not by default so that you could activate that profile only on machines where you do have docker (e.g. a build server).

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do that. All you need is to specify via properties which Rabbit instance do you wan to connect to. Here are just a few:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host
spring.rabbitmq.port
spring.rabbitmq.username
. . .
```